# Derive new column of weekly unique users alongside daily unique users in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table where I have daily unique users in the month of January. I am trying to derive a new column (in the same table) that shows total weekly unique users.

I am already successful at creating a column that shows week number but somehow I am not able to find the overall weekly sum in a new column. Below is the MySQL code which I have tried.

```
SELECT 
    DATE(`event_timestamp`) AS `Date`,
    WEEK(`event_timestamp`, 0) AS `Week`,
    COUNT(DISTINCT `user_id`) AS `Unique_Users`
FROM 
    events
GROUP BY 
    DATE(`event_timestamp`),
    WEEK(`event_timestamp`, 0);
```

[image]

What I would love is to get another column in the same query with unique weekly users. Could someone please help me with this? Thanks. :)

Comment: What is wrong with your current query?

Comment: are you going to show per day or per week?

Comment: I am not able to figure out a way to get the sum of week 0, 1, 2, 3 in a new column. For Eg, the new column should show 30 (sum of 0 week) opposite to each row of 0 week (the first 5 rows).

Comment: Wouldn't a simple rollup be better? You will get the weekly sums in a new record as opposed to a new column, but would make more sense than repeating the weekly numbers.

Comment: @ϻᴇᴛᴀʟ if possible, both daily and weekly in the same table.

Comment: @Shadow yeah (I was able to do that). But someone has asked me to show them in the same table. I am not sure if it is possible or not. That's why I thought of asking out to the community.

Comment: With rollup the weekly totals would be in the same table, just in an extra row. It is possible to display the weekly counts to a column as well with a subquery.

Comment: @Shadow Makes sense. I will try to use subquery way. Will let you know if I am successful.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

One method is to flag each user for each week to identify the first record in the week.  Then you can use a sum over that value for the entire week:

```
SELECT DATE(`event_timestamp`) AS `Date`,
       WEEK(`event_timestamp`, 0) AS `Week`,
       COUNT(DISTINCT `user_id`) AS `Unique_Users`,
       SUM( SUM(seqnum = 1) ) OVER (PARTITION BY week(event_timestamp) as weekly_uniques
FROM (SELECT e.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id, WEEK(event_timestamp) ORDER BY event_timestamp) as seqnum
      FROM events e 
     ) e
GROUP BY DATE(`event_timestamp`), WEEK(`event_timestamp`, 0);
```

Note:  If you are dealing with weeks, you should be taking the year into account.